# AngularJs Directive update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to update my directive content only at some desired places, but not at others. I have simulated my problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2945/

The problem is, I have an 'editor' directive which is applied in two places:

- `<span class="editor1" editor ></span>`
- `<span class="editor2" editor ></span>`

I want to update the content of `span class="editor1"` on button click.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not go with a relatively ***Angularesque*** approach by isolating the scope of the directive and to a maximum extent, avoid jQuery in your logic.

So you could have your directive defined as such:

```
.directive('editor', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      upd : '=',
      editordata : '=data'
    },
    template: '<div>{{editordata}}</div>',
    controller: function($scope, $rootScope, $element) {

      $rootScope.$on('update', function(evt, data) {      
        if(data.upd === $scope.upd){
          $scope.editordata = data.txt;
        }
      })
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {}
  }
})
```

Here, you are passing the required information which the `editor` directive depends upon through its `scope`, namely `upd` (which I suppose is how you want to uniquely identify the items by) and the text `data`.

Meanwhile, you can define a list of the editor items in the common parent controller `MyCtrl` and iterate over them in the DOM with `ng-repeat`.

```
// MyCtrl controller
$scope.list = [
  {upd: 'editor1', data: 'original data for editor1'},
  {upd: 'editor1', data: 'original data for editor2'}
]

<!-- HTML -->
<div ng-repeat="item in list" upd="item.upd" data="item.data"></div>
```

### [***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/Lvc0u55v/2952/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the current directory has the "editor1" class and if so complete your logic.
You can look at this example :
    element[0].querySelector('.editor1') !== undefined'

Comment: I have to use this logic using $element in controller of my directive. thanks a lot.